# Doctrine, different file names, different tables generation

Tags: php, doctrine

I am trying to create tables from models using the **createTablesFromModels** method of Doctrine. I have a `/model` folder where I keep my models but it depends on the file names how the tables are generated.

Inside 3 files I have the following:

```
class Item extends Doctrine_Record {

public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('nombre', 'string', 45, array(
        'notnull' => true
    ));
    $this->hasColumn('enunciado', 'string', 90, array(
        'notnull' => true
    ));
    $this->hasColumn('imagen_reposo', 'string', 90);
    $this->hasColumn('imagen_movimiento', 'string', 90);
}

public function setUp() {
    $this->hasMany('Prueba as Pruebas', array(
        'refClass' => 'ItemPrueba',
        'local' => 'item_id',
        'foreign' => 'prueba_id'
    ));
}
}
```

---

```
class Prueba extends Doctrine_Record {

public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('nombre', 'string', 45, array(
        'notnull' => true
    ));
    $this->hasColumn('consigna', 'clob', 65535);
    $this->hasColumn('consentimiento', 'clob', 65535);
    $this->hasColumn('codigo', 'string', 45);
}

public function setUp() {
    $this->hasMany('Item as Items', array(
        'refClass' => 'ItemPrueba',
        'local' => 'prueba_id',
        'foreign' => 'item_id'
    ));
}
}
```

---

```
class ItemPrueba extends Doctrine_Record {

public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('item_id', 'integer', null, array(
        'primary' => true
    ));
    $this->hasColumn('prueba_id', 'integer', null, array(
        'primary' => true
    ));
}
}
```

I just want to do a many to many relation.
When I use this names:

```
/models/tableone.php
/models/tabletwo.php
/models/tableoneTabletwo.php
```

it creates the following tables **with** the relations.

http://i52.tinypic.com/25hpdo2.png

When I use this names:

```
/models/item.php
/models/prueba.php
/models/itemPrueba.php
```

it creates the tables **without any** relations

more info:
I am using codeIgniter framework and added Doctrine 1.2 as a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
$this->setTableName('tablename');
```

should do what you need. Doctrine uses some conventions to identify relations and tables. It usually guesses the name of the table based on the class but I've seen this failing many times. Setting the table name should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, it didn't work. I had to change the file name prueba.php to prueb.php. Weird solution, I still don't know why I can't use the file name prueba.php in my model class.